# check and uncheck all checkboxes in dynamic grid

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a dynamic datagrid(Datatables) displaying 10 rows initially with checkboxes in one column. there is a button at the bottom of the table which will be enabled when atleast one box is checked. Now, when i click on one checkbox and go for the display of next 10 records in grid and come back to the previous records, the button is disabled.

```
<div class="table-responsive datagrid">




<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table voa-grid" id="example">
<thead class="thead">
    <tr>

        <th>Given Names</th>
        <th>Family Name</th>
        <th>gender</th>
        <th>Nationality</th>
        <th>Date of Birth</th>
        <th>Travel Doc No</th>
        <th>TD Issuing State</th>
        <th>Passport Issue Date</th>
        <th>Payment Transaction No</th>
        <th>Visa Application No</th>
        <th>Visa Issued</th>
        <th>Visa Issue Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Steven</td>
        <td>Gerrard</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">British</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>C90838383</td>
        <td>England</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1001</td>
        <td>VA1001</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Fernando</td>
        <td>Torres</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">Spanish</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>D90</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1002</td>
        <td>VA1001</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Lukas</td>
        <td>Poldoski</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">German</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>B9083</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1003</td>
        <td>VA1006</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Zlatan</td>
        <td>Ibrahimovic</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">Swedish</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>D90838383</td>
        <td>Sweden</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1001</td>
        <td>VA1008</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
<td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Robin</td>
        <td>Van Persie</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">Dutch</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>A90838383</td>
        <td>Netherlands</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1001</td>
        <td>VA1002</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Xabi</td>
        <td>Alonso</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">Spanish</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>C90838383</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1001</td>
        <td>VA1005</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>



    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Xabi</td>
        <td>Alonso</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">Spanish</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>C90838383</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1001</td>
        <td>VA1005</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>



    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Xabi</td>
        <td>Alonso</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">Spanish</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>C90838383</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1001</td>
        <td>VA1005</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>



    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Xabi</td>
        <td>Alonso</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">Spanish</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>C90838383</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1001</td>
        <td>VA1005</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>



    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Xabi</td>
        <td>Alonso</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">Spanish</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>C90838383</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1001</td>
        <td>VA1005</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>



    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Xabi</td>
        <td>Alonso</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">Spanish</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>C90838383</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1001</td>
        <td>VA1005</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>



    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Xabi</td>
        <td>Alonso</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">Spanish</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>C90838383</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1001</td>
        <td>VA1005</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>



    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Xabi</td>
        <td>Alonso</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">Spanish</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>C90838383</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1001</td>
        <td>VA1005</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>



    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Xabi</td>
        <td>Alonso</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">Spanish</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>C90838383</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1001</td>
        <td>VA1005</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>



    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Xabi</td>
        <td>Alonso</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td class="center">Spanish</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>C90838383</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>04 Feb 2006</td>
        <td>PAY1001</td>
        <td>VA1005</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>












</tbody>
<tfoot>

</tfoot>
</table>



</div>











  $(".voa-grid").delegate("input[type='checkbox']","click", function(){

      $(this).each(function(index, element) {

            if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                $(this).addClass( "voa-tr-checked" );
                $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
                var vor_checked_one = $(".voa-grid").find(".voa-tr-   checked").size();

                if(vor_checked_one > 0){
                $(".update").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            }

            else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                $(this).removeClass( "voa-tr-checked" );
                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                var vor_checked_two = $(".voa-grid").find(".voa-tr-checked").size();

                if(vor_checked_two == 0){
                $(".update").prop("disabled", true);
                }
            }  
        });

  });

});
```

Comment: You just need a function to check and uncheck all checkboxes? If you want just that, you can simple add a checkbox e.g. in header and add a class in your other checkboxes and create a function to check - uncheck when click header checkbox.

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/Animeshjain/PJ67B/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I´m assuming that you are using [Datatables.net](https://datatables.net/)

If so, you need to use their API to achieve this. As raw jQuery usage on the html does not get synced with the state datatables has. Datatables manages its own state and rerenders the tables with the state and data it has saved. if you just change the html, datatable will never know what you did.

You could use this [example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html) (without checkbox, but with complete row selection), where you can select a row, and if you change the page, and then go back, the row is still selected.

Than you might search for `tr.selected` and if one exists the button would be enabled

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble understanding your question, but am I right in thinking the checkbox at the bottom should be check if any of the others are. In that case I think I might have found the problem:

```
    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
            $(this).removeClass( "voa-tr-checked" );
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
```

In this code it sounds like you are telling the bottom checkbox to become unchecked whenever you uncheck any of the other buttons. I may have got the completely wrong end of the stick but if the bottom checkbox is to be checked when any or all of the others are, surely it shouldn't be unchecked when one of the others is unchecked.

Hopefully I am talking sense but its entirely possible I have no idea what I am on about, so apologies in advance if that is the case..